# How to get to closest (nice) beach around Heraklion

Tags: greece, beaches

I'm going to Heraklion for a short time because of my job, and fortunately I have half a day off.

I would like to go to a nice beach.

However, looking at the map, it looks like Heraklion is on a harbour.

What is the closest beach (hopefully nice) to Heraklion? Is it possible to get there by bus or any other public transport?

Answer (score 1):

After asking here and to a few locals, it turned out that a good option was **Agia Pelagia**
(pics and map [here](https://www.google.gr/maps/place/Ag.+Pelagia+715+00/@35.404407,25.01934,3a,75y,315h,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s28225908!2e1!3e10!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2Fproxy%2FwBVVOUMVYCBtZYSOEeB_VsCsGkd031xLmtHsvBtWn0YCli4JqB5X-LDhfyp3fqNSyCyXy8EBm76idp4ZI-d3FHMIn_apOA%3Dw203-h125!7i1146!8i709!4m5!3m4!1s0x149a5199580d6779:0xa00bd2f74c28f90!8m2!3d35.4072951!4d25.0181002!6m1!1e1?hl=it) )

It's really a nice place, very relaxing, with lots of choices for something to eat and a lounge beach bar at the west side.

It's at about ~20km away but it's maybe faster to go there by bus than to other closer beaches on foot.

There is a bus service for Agia Pealgia, that brings very close to the beach in a few minutes (usually starts at line 5 at the [main bus station](https://www.google.gr/maps/@35.3414125,25.1390248,3a,75y,165.21h,79.56t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1siuxjSWTEG_vUUZsB4aAO5w!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1?hl=it) in Heraklion, ). The bus takes about 50 minutes to go, and around 30 to come back to Heraklion.

In the picture below you can find the bus timetable.

[image: BUs Timetable]

Comment: guys.... there was another answer suggesting another interesting spot. Any clue why it disappeared?